# How to optimize the algorithm of finding maximum element in each possible subarrays of an array

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I have been thinking about one particular problem in which I have to find a maximum element of each window.

i.e. find

$\max(i,j) = \max\{a[i],a[i+1],\ldots ,a[j]\}$, where $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$.

Naive approach will run wth $O(n^3)$ time complexity,but I have optimized that upto some extent.
Till now this is what I have done.

```
for(int gap=2;gap<=n;gap++){
        for(int i=1,j=gap;j<=n;i++,j++){
            maxval[i] = max(maxval[i],val[j]);
            cout << "window is: " << i << ":" << j << endl;
            cout << "max of window is:" << maxval[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

This algorithm runs with $O(n^2)$ time complexity.

Is there any way to optimize this algorithm?

Comment: small optimizations related to the specific language, why not?  But, you make only one computation by result and memory is not much so sollicited ( $maxval[]$ ). How to hope better ?

Comment: @igael I guess algorithm should be language-independent, and I am taking maxval[] array to calculate the max of new window based on the knowledge of the previous window.

Comment: in this case, bravo, I don't see how you can enhance a ratio like 1 computation by sub result

Comment: Is this is the best far I can go in terms of optimization in this algorithm?

Comment: yes, rearranging the loops is just a matter of style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a : \{1,\ldots,n\}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a function representing your array. Then you can build array $b$ of size $n\times \lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor$ such that

$$b[i,j]=\max\{a[i\ldots i+2^j-1]\},$$

and answer any $\max(x,y)$ queries in *constant* time using

$$\max(x,y)=\max\{b[x,z],b[y-2^z+1,z]\}$$

where $z=\lfloor \log_2(y-x+1) \rfloor$. Note that $b$ can be precomputed in $O(n\log n)$ time.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: What is the logic behind this idea?

Comment: @unlucy7735 I think it should be quite clear, just ponder about it for a while.

Comment: I have compare your algo with mine, and it seems like that your algo is not giving the proper answer. Check this please.http://ideone.com/CbzAS2 
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Sure I will check it, perhaps some misplaced $-1$, but not right now, I'm on a mobile.

Comment: my bad. I apologise for my mistake. I did not code properly. It is working as expected. Thank you very much. This is the updated code. http://ideone.com/8PjjdY